# How to use conditional operator or_ in sqlalchemy with conditional if?

Tags: python, optimization, sqlalchemy, refactoring

Existing code snippet:

```
if sup_usr_only:
    query_ob = query_ob.filter(
        or_(
            and_(
                Department.id.in_(login_user.department_ids),  # logic is OK - checked.
                model.visibility == VISIBLE_DEPT
            ),

            and_(
                model.visibility == VISIBLE_COMPANY,
                model.company_id == login_user.company_id
            ))
    )
else:
    query_ob = query_ob.filter(
        or_(
            and_(
                Department.id.in_(login_user.department_ids),  # logic is OK - checked.
                model.visibility == VISIBLE_DEPT
            ),
            model.visibility == VISIBLE_GLOBAL,
            and_(
                model.visibility == VISIBLE_COMPANY,
                model.company_id == login_user.company_id
            ))
    )
```

If there is a way that I can minimize code snippet with in line if check or any other optimization?
Want to make this like below (which is syntactically wrong):

```
query_ob = query_ob.filter(
            or_(
                and_(
                    Department.id.in_(login_user.department_ids),
                    model.visibility == VISIBLE_DEPT
                ),
                model.visibility == VISIBLE_GLOBAL if not sup_usr_only,
                and_(
                    model.visibility == VISIBLE_COMPANY,
                    model.company_id == login_user.company_id
                ))
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your arguments to `or_` in a list up-front, then apply them to the `or_()` function:

```
options = [
    and_(
        Department.id.in_(login_user.department_ids),
        model.visibility == VISIBLE_DEPT
    ),
    and_(
        model.visibility == VISIBLE_COMPANY,
        model.company_id == login_user.company_id
    )]

if not sup_usr_only:
    options.append(model.visibility == VISIBLE_GLOBAL)

query_ob = query_ob.filter(or_(*options))
```

To a database it doesn't matter what order the options are listed in for an `OR` statement, but if you feel the order matters to your application you can use `options.insert(1, model.visibility == VISIBLE_GLOBAL)` too.